# Automatic conversion of int to unsigned int

Tags: c++, casting, int, conventions

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int u = 5;
    int x = -1;
    if(x>u) {
        cout<<"Should not happen"<<endl;
    } else {
        cout<<"Ok"<<endl;
    }
}
```

This code outputs `Should not happen`. I came across this when comparing the size of a string (size_t is an unsigned int or unsigned long long value) to an int.
It seems that C type casts int to unsigned int but in practice, it seems it would bring in bugs. Honestly, I would have preferred a compile-time error given how incompatible int is to unsigned int. I would like to know why the convention is like this?

Comment: Because C++ is based on C, which is an old language with imperfections. Modern compilers will warn on this.

Comment: Yep, GCC says: `warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-compare]`: https://godbolt.org/z/u4ThsT and [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYs7DsIwEER7n2IVmlCkoKCKyRUoKKgte@NYOGvLHykSytUxMZ8CMcVIb3ee9L7TUpayMyRtVgjcuJgCinlgORrSQGLG6IVEiEn1jBlKMAtD7R7uDLZkikYTKqifDCc49q97xWXD7vDhsV2G/LVqpMuJ8@YyuWwVkEswCe@RGs6RlH1rK6CN@G@db78ztpbykKMVOpbuKqzdGkNw4Qk "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online"). Clang doesn't complain at all

Comment: I use Clang++17 and did not get a compile-time error.

Comment: `-Wsign-compare` is included in `-Wextra` on Clang. I recommend always using at least both `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

Comment: msvc warns `signed/unsigned mismatch`

Comment: @MohammadSheraj Warnings are not compile-time errors. This is perfectly legal C++

Comment: In evaluating the expression `x > u`, `x` is converted to `unsigned` - so `-1` becomes the largest value an `unsigned` can represent.  That is greater than the value of `5` (more accurately `5u`) stored in the variable `u`.   This is well defined in C++, so not an error, but most modern compilers can be *configured*  (e.g. command line options) to give a warning on this conversion - and some can be configured to treat warnings like errors.

Comment: Clang warns me.  I have warnings enabled.  Do you have warnings enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable `-Wsign-compare -Werror` in Clang: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY67DsIwDEX3fIVVljJ0YGBq6C8wMDBbidtGpE6Uh1QJ9dcJLY8BcQdbx/aRrLxvlEUeStkZVjZrAmlcTIFw6kSOhgdgnCh6VAQx6VYIwwkmNFzv4S5gTeZoBiYN2ybDCY7ta77hvGJz@HBfz13@WluUy0nK6jK6bDWwSzCi98SVlMTavrUFyEb6t8633zOxlPJQvcUhluaK1q6VQnBh7duDjXKTx0BP)

It'll produce a compile-time error (because of `-Werror` that treats warnings as errors):

```
.code.tio.cpp:7:9: error: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned int' [-Werror,-Wsign-compare]
    if(x>u) {
       ~^~
1 error generated.
```

For some reason, `-Wall -Werror` in Clang (but not in GCC) doesn't produce any errors. But `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` does include `-Wsign-compare`, so you can use that.

Comment: I imagine it's not in `-Wall` because of all the valid `for (int i = 0; i < something.size(); ++i)` code out there.

Comment: @chris That's not valid though either as the return type of `size()` for containers (which is generally `std::size_t`) is not necessarily `sizeof(int)`

Comment: @NotAProgrammer, I mean valid in that going over the limit of `int` is something most of that code never has to worry about.

Comment: For Clang, I use: `-Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -pedantic -fsanitize=undefined,null,address,bounds,bool,enum`